# What is the idea behind the CANopen Transparent Mode?

Tags: communication, can-bus, canopen

There is quite a lot of literature available for understanding the concept of CANopen Master/Client, however I couldn't find any sources that describe the principle idea of the CANopen Transparent Mode. The only source I could find was this [Siemens Manual](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/971/109760971/att_967877/v1/109760971_network_transitions_pncan_transparent_en.pdf).

Can someone explain this concept in a comprehensive way? Thanks!

Comment: "Can you recommend any literature/books/websites?" No, because such questions are explicitly off-topic. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Here's an idea though: read the open CANopen standard.

Answer (score -1):

I think it means listen to the communications, but don't respond or ever send a packet.  That's also known as "Silent" mode.  Just a guess